# Dynamic element inside several 'li'

Tags: java, selenium

now I have more complicated (at least for me) and struggling to find element (which is dynamic one - changes on daily basis). Following is how it looks on page. On top is '**ul**'

```
<ul class="feed-tips" id="Grid"
```

Below are 50 '**li**' with same name:

```
<li class="feed-item vevent tip-list-row"
```

Below one of those '**li**' are

```
<div class="tip medium-9 small-12 column padding-reset dtstart tip-list-row__tip">
<a href="link to a page" class="summary url">Heading4</a>
```

So, link to a page & Heading4 (in '**href**') are dynamic ones and it will be useless from i.e tomorrow.
Above is 5th 'li' in the list and I tried to find element with css selector but it does not work - here is what I tried:

```
    //Open 5th from the list
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Grid > li:nth-child(5) > div.tip.medium-9.small-12.column.padding-reset.dtstart.tip-list-row__tip > div.tip-match.medium-12.column > div.tip-teams > a")).click();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tried xpath also, here is it:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="Grid"]/li[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a"))

Comment: @Zoran The CSS in original post does not match the html  source you have added. There are 2 additional divs in the css which are absent in the source. If there is only one link in the 50 li's why bother with using index. Just use "ul[id='Grid'] > li a[class='summary url']".

Comment: @Grasshopper - I must made a mistake somewhere when creating question - Idea were to not create a long question. Regarding those lines cssselector and xpath they are directly picked from page. They are correct - just xpath is actually 3rd element, not 5th.

Comment: @Grasshopper here is hierarchical list of elements: '1) ul class or id =Grid 2) li class= feed-item vevent tip-list-row 3) div class = tip medium-9 small-12 column padding-reset dtstart tip-list-row__tip  4) div class = tip-match medium-12 column 5) div class= tip-teams 6) a href ' (is the last)

Comment: your problem statement is not clear, do you want to get link with name `Heading4`? or something else?

Comment: @ Gaurang Shah - exactly - that element I want to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are trying to find the anchor element with dynamic href, you can use somewhat the xpath as below:

//ul[@id='Grid']/li//div[contains(@class, 'tip-teams')]//a[@href]

I did not understand the total problem, but it will list down all the links with attribute href within that hierarchy. In this case, do not use any sort of indexing. Also, not required to drill down all the levels of hierarchy.

//a[@href] - It will provide you all links with @href without comparing any value.